# Как правильно реализовать бесконечный цикл?

Tags: android, kotlin, while, android-service

В проекте есть сервис MyService. В методе onStartCommand() есть цикл while, но при запуске методе в ожидании приложение выдает ошибку. Как мне правильно реализовать бесконечный цикл?

Код MyService:

```
package com.example.anticondesate

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.widget.Toast

class WarmerService : Service() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Сервис запущен!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        var value: Long = 1
        while (true) {
            value++
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Сервис остановлен!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

При запуске сервиса даже не срабатывает Toast.

Как реализовать данный цикл?

Comment: Что написано в ошибке?

Comment: Приложение зависает в фоне, логах нет ошибок. Система Android говорит в приложении произошла ошибка

Comment: `onStartCommand()` вызывается в главном потоке, вы его зациклили и тем самым заморозили всё приложение (UI, жизненный цикл, события). Нужно запустить поток и в нём уже выполнять длительные задачи.

Comment: woesss, тоесть нужно использовать классы Thread, Runnable и т. д?

Comment: woesss, спасибо большое за просвещение! У меня все получилось!!!